# cascade rules of styling in css

Tags: css, css-cascade

I have an `<a>` tag

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com">GOOGLE</a>
```

with following styles:

```css
a {
  color: red
}

a:hover {
  color: green
}

a:active {
  color: blueviolet
}

a:visited {
  color: brown;
}
```

Here is my problem :

`a:hover` And `a:active` Are ignored

I Know This Is for Cascade Rules But
I want to know ***best practice*** to solve it.

**I tried adding `!important`** and it **worked** as I wanted.

**I changed line numbers** (because importancy and specification are equal so line number is important) and it **worked correctly** But I want to know which solution is best !!

adding important is not a good idea in most cases
and line number is changing in development.

***Can I have some kind of selector like this?:***

```css
a:not(:hover):visited {
  color: blue
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assumed `a:hover` and `a:active` are ignored **if the link has been visited**. If that is the case, try this:

```css
a {
    color: red
}

a:hover,
a:visited:hover {
    color: green
}

a:active,
a:visited:active {
    color: blueviolet
}

a:visited {
    color: brown;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com">GOOGLE</a>
```

---

> can I have some kind of selector like this ?
> `a:not(:hover):visited { color: blue }`

Yes, you can.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you read [this Tutorial](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/css-links.php). According to that one:

> In general, the order of the pseudo classes should be the following — :link, :visited, :hover, :active, :focus in order for these to work properly.

so If you change your **CSS** file to this one it must be worked correctly:

```css
a:link {
    color: red
}

a:visited {
    color: green
}

a:hover {
    color: blueviolet
}

a:focus {
    color: rgb(230, 49, 175);
}
```

If you think that **hover** and **active** or ... does not work properly, maybe it is because you have visited the link before. try to change the "href" address to see that they are working.

Answer (score 0):

When setting the style for several link states, there are some order rules:

`a:hover` **MUST** come after `a:link` and `a:visited`
`a:active` **MUST** come after `a:hover`

```css
a:link {
  color: red
}

a:visited {
  color: brown;
}

a:hover {
  color: green
}

a:active {
  color: blueviolet
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com">GOOGLE</a>
```

[See this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp) to know more about link and their states like `hover` `visited` order

Answer (score -1):

First, you forgot the **semicolon**
Second, if !important **works**, just use it.
Third, I have **never** met this selector before.
See further about this on W3School

Comment: Don't encourage the `!important` use. [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). Using it makes code harder to understand.

Comment: `!important` should really be reserved only for those cases in which you need to override some external library styles that have not provided other means for you to do so.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).